# -Webkit-transform translation not animating

Tags: css, animation, translation

I would like an `li` to gradually slide 100px to the right. My CSS translation is working instantly, but the animation is not. Can anybody explain why?
JSFiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/Lux4t/1/

```
<ul>
    <li class="ease"><a href="">Ease</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS

```
li{
list-style: none;
margin-bottom:20px;
float:left;
clear: both;
}
li a{
color:white;
background-color:blue;
display:block;
height:100px;
width:200px;
transition-property:-webkit-transform;
}
li.ease a{
transition-timing-function: ease;
}
li:hover a{
-webkit-transform:translateX(100px);
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transition-property` is a part of `transition` (a shorthand). `transition-property` also needs a `transition-duration` to work. Use `transition` instead, its easier to write

**CSS**

```
li a {
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
```

See [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lux4t/2/)

Comment: Thanks that works. But transition-property is a property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property I wonder why my version is not working...

Comment: I seriously saw that for the first time O_O. `Transition-property` is a property, ... weird

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: needed to add `transition-duration:3s;` to my `li a` css!

Comment: Haha, we found it at the same time :P